# Evaluating an object chain with selectors

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector

Consider an object chain like:

```
foo.bar.baz.bing
```

In this particular instance, I am given `foo` and I wish to evaluate the method `bing`. In code I would do the following:

```
[[[foo bar] baz] bing];
```

Or, if `bing` were a property, I could evaluate it thusly:

```
id result = foo.bar.baz.bing;
```

Now consider the situation where I am given `foo` and then `bar.baz.bing` in the form of an NSString object. I came up with the following method to evaluate down to `bing`, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do this.

```
- (id)evaluator:(id)parentObject withChain:(NSString *)objectChain
{
    id currentObject = parentObject;

    for (NSString *component in [objectChain componentsSeparatedByString:@"."])
    {

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
        currentObject = [currentObject performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(component)];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }
    return currentObject;
}
```

Note: The above code example was contrived to demonstrate the point. I am aware of the dangers of calling `init`, `alloc`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`, or `new` using a method like this. The actual use in code is very carefully managed to avoid any situations where ARC would require a release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).

```
[parentObject valueForKeyPath:objectChain];
```